# how to combine queries yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a query with 2 tables. I want to combine these two queries into one query. how do?

```
public function actionGroup()
{
    $query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['lao',new \yii\db\Expression('COUNT(lao)'),'nama_ptgs', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(outstanding)')])
                ->from('debitur')
                ->groupBy('lao')
                ->all();

    $query2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['lao', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(tgt_pergeseran)')])
                ->from('resume')
                ->groupBy('lao')
                ->all();

    return $this->render('outstanding', [
        'query1' => $query1,
        'query2' => $query2,
    ]);
}
```

example [sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYTi9.png)

```
SELECT debitur.lao, debitur.Outstanding, debitur.jumlah, resume.Target FROM ( SELECT lao, SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding, COUNT(lao) as jumlah FROM debitur GROUP BY lao )debitur INNER JOIN ( SELECT lao, SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as Target FROM resume GROUP BY lao ) resume ON debitur.lao = resume.lao
```

error [undefined index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2y1H.png)

print($query);
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmDZA.png)

Comment: What result do you want to achieve? How should the final query in raw SQL look like?

Comment: provide your raw SQL query so we can have an idea what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: The final in raw SQL. updated my post @Yerke

Comment: my raw SQL query
I added it to my post @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: is that a complete query without any `where()` condition in the main query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw query you provided does not have any `where()` condition for the main query

```
 SELECT debitur.lao, debitur.Outstanding, debitur.jumlah, resume.Target 
 FROM 
    (SELECT lao, SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding, COUNT(lao) as jumlah FROM debitur GROUP BY lao) debitur 
 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT lao, SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as Target FROM resume GROUP BY lao) resume 
 ON  debitur.lao = resume.lao
```

If that is the complete and correct query that show you the right results in the phpmyadmin widow, you need to use the sub query like below

```
$subQueryFrom = new \yii\db\Query();
$subQueryFrom->select(['lao', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(outstanding) as Outstanding, COUNT(lao) as jumlah')])
    ->from('debitur')
    ->groupBy('lao');

$subQueryJoin = new \yii\db\Query();
$subQueryJoin->select(['lao', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as Target')])
    ->from('resume')
    ->groupBy('lao');

$query = new \yii\db\Query();

$results = $query->select(['debitur.lao', 'debitur.Outstanding', 'debitur.jumlah', 'resume.Target'])
    ->from(['debitur' => $subQueryFrom])
    ->innerJoin(['resume' => $subQueryJoin], 'debitur.lao = resume.lao')
    ->all();
```

You can now use the `$result` in your view which holds the records against your query.

```
return $this->render('outstanding', [
        'results' => $results,
]);
```

Comment: @UcupRahmat You should use `lao` as index instead of `debitur.lao`.

Comment: @UcupRahmat you should change the  `$team['deitur.lao']` to `$team['lao']`

Comment: still error Undefined index: lao, sir @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: @UcupRahmat can you use `print_r()` on the resultset returned by `$query` and add the array to your question

Comment: @UcupRahmat  that is not the result you are printing the query show the results for the query, i updated the code above to store the results into the `$results` var for the query see the answer and show the result set retrieved by the query.

Comment: Awesome, and life saving!

Answer (score 1):

In order to combine the results from 2 queries from 2 different tables you can use the [Union Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). From the link there are necessary conditions though:

> 1. Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
>      columns
> 2. The columns must also have similar data types
> 3. The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

In order for this to work for you, you need to alter your queries as follows:

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
              ->select(['lao',
                         new \yii\db\Expression('COUNT(lao) as count_column'),
                         'nama_ptgs', 
                         new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(outstanding) as sum_column'),
                         new \yii\db\Expression('NULL as tgt_sum')])
              ->from('debitur')
              ->groupBy('lao');

$query2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['lao',
                           new \yii\db\Expression('NULL as count_column'),
                           new \yii\db\Expression('NULL as nama_ptgs'),
                           new \yii\db\Expression('NULL as sum_column'), 
                           new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(tgt_pergeseran) as tgt_sum'),
                ])->from('resume')
                ->groupBy('lao');
```

In short if your first table contains columns a and b, and your second contains columns a and c. Then what you need to do is `select(['a','b','NULL as c'])` from the first and `select(['a','NULL as b','c'])` from the second so that you can combine the two results

Then the combined query is simply:

```
$combinedQuery = $query1->union($query2);
```

Comment: sorry i get erorr "Call to a member function union() on array". and I have added a sql query in my post. thank you

Comment: Can you send here the code that you used :)
I mean the code that you used when you got this error

Comment: Yes there was a mistake, because I cant test this code :)
I edited now. The error was because all() was used in the two queries meaning that the results are retrieved before the union. The union is done on queries though.
Anyways, please try now and update me on how it goes :)